# Hijri or Jalali Calendar in processmaker 3.2

Tags: calendar, hijri, processmaker, jalali-calendar

How to change the processmaker 3.2 environment to Hijri or Jalali Calendar?
for example : I wanth use Hijri or Jalali Calender in "Inbox,Draft,Participation,Last Modified,Due Date,Summeary,..."
It is different with use date picker in dynaform
For example see the link below
[Hijri or Jalali Calendar in processmaker 3.2](https://download-by-satoshi.com/free-download/topic/hijri-jalali-calendar-processmaker-3-2/)
Thank

Answer (score 1):

Your can see this link for use jalali calendar for dynaforms:
https://www.aparat.com/v/chENo

But for use jalali calendar for lists in main menu or admin menu and etc
you must use php jalali function and change core of program.
Therefore you must know the paths and structure.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently I need to change the application core.
thanks for your response